# File stream with inputted file name

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream

I want to prompt the user for the file name then use that name to open up a file stream.  I think I need to make it into a const char or something but I dont really know what that is or how to do so.

```
cout << "Enter Locations Filename: "<<endl;
cin>> locFilename;

ifstream locations(locFilename);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correction:

```
cout << "Enter Location's Filename: ";
getline(cin, locFilename);
ifstream locations(locFilename.c_str();
```

Input and output are two separate functions in C++.
Some versions of C++ require a C-style string for the file open method.